# Can't seem to get the argc correct (cs50 problem set 2 )

Tags: c, arguments, command, line, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{


if (argc != 2)
{

    printf("Incorrect number of arguments, try again");
    return 1;
}
else{printf("Congrats\n");}


printf("argv is: %s",argv[1]);





}
```

The code is incomplete and the task is for me to receive an input from the user via command line argument and to encrypt it. However I cannot seem to get the correct comman line argument. For example if input is "ceaser.exe 2" where ceaser is the name of my executable file and 2 is my input, argv[1] shows as "2ceaser.execeaser.exe".

Have watched a lot of vids but seems like theres nothing wrong with the format of my code but can't seem to solve this issue. The output I want for argv[1] should be "2" but can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 1):

You declared your main function incorrectly. `argv` should be of type `char**` or `char*[]`, not `char**[]`.

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```